# Creating a function between rows in a dataframe (R)

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply

I currently have a dataframe (also I have the data in xts format but I don't know in which format it will be easier to apply the function) consisting of around 50 stocks and their prices across a 21 year span. I want to create a function in R that applies to the dataframe in a way that each row will carry out an operation with another row a certain number before it. For example, I want the values in the first row to be added to those in the second row, the values in the second row to be added to those in the third row and so on. The actual function I want applied is a little more complicated than this but it is just the format of applying the function that is causing me difficultly.

I have messed around with apply() but cannot seem to get the function working. Any help would be appreciated. I have provided a sample of my data that I am trying to work with.

```
Date       AT10Y DE10Y SEK10Y   OMX `USD/SEK` UK10Y FTSE_AllShare `GBP/USD` ES10Y
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1997-01-01  0     0      0        0      0     0               0       1.71  0   
 2 1997-01-02  5.91  5.98   6.84     0      6.86  7.70         1990.      1.69  6.97
 3 1997-01-03  6.00  5.94   6.85     0      6.91  7.68         2004.      1.69  6.94
 4 1997-01-06  6.00  5.97   6.86     0      6.95  7.72         2013.      1.68  6.94
 5 1997-01-07  6.00  5.96   6.86     0      6.96  7.73         2004.      1.70  6.98
 6 1997-01-08  5.97  5.93   6.82     0      6.97  7.71         2009.      1.69  6.94
 7 1997-01-09  5.92  5.89   6.70     0      6.92  7.64         2008.      1.69  6.89
 8 1997-01-10  5.92  5.91   6.75     0      6.90  7.63         1997.      1.68  6.92
 9 1997-01-13  5.83  5.82   6.67     0      6.94  7.56         2018.      1.67  6.74
10 1997-01-14  5.82  5.78   6.61     0      6.97  7.54         2043.      1.67  6.73
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function you're looking for is `dplyr::lag` or `lead`. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html

For example:

```
require(dplyr)
mutate(df, newsum=at10y+lead(at10y))
```

will give you a column of at10y where every line is the sum of this row plus the next one.

Comment: This definitely looks like what I need thank you. One more note, how would I apply the same function to each column instead of just to the first column like your example gave?

Comment: Apologies, I solved this alone using mutate_at. Thanks a lot for your help!